# PHP equivalent of Java's unescapeJava() function

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding

What is the PHP equivalent of the following Java function?

```
str = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);
```

This function is present in [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) and following is the description of the function

> Unescapes any Java literals found in the String. For example, it will
>   turn a sequence of '\' and 'n' into a newline character, unless the
>   '\' is preceded by another '\'.

**Edit**

One solution I found is this

```
echo json_decode('"' . $str . '"');
```

But I think there should be some other elegant solution to it.

**Edit 2**

As @julp suggested, `transliterate` is another option, but it works only on PHP 5.4 and higher. Unfortunately I am still on PHP 5.3 and need a solution that will work in PHP 5.3

Comment: PHP does this automatically with string inside double quotes `"`

Comment: @Dale It doesn't do it when I have unicode characters like `\u2002` etc.

Comment: @Sudar php doesn't support `\uxxxx`-escape sequences

Comment: @Esailija While PHP string syntax does not support unicode escape sequences, PHP's json_decode function will properly decode those characters into valid bytes. For example `var_dump(json_decode('"\u2002"'));` will return a 3 byte string that correctly represents those unicode bytes.

Comment: @GoogleGuy yeah but it's not simple as that, you now need `escapeJSONString` function

Comment: @Esailija You mean json_encode?

Comment: @GoogleGuy no, if you just do `json_decode(json_encode($str)))` what do you think will happen? You need some screwed up homemade escapeJSONString that has special treatment for not escaping `\u` to make it work.

Comment: @Esailija I would never do that to begin with. That also depends entirely on what's in $str and why I'm using json_encode on it in the first place. If $str is a unicode string PHP's json_encode will properly **encode** it using unicode escape sequences. In which case json_decode will also properly **decode** it. So, I have no idea what you're talking about or what escapeJSONString would do.

Comment: @GoogleGuy consider `$input` is `\u00e4"`. Now, if you do `json_decode( '"' . $input . '"' )` what do you think will happen?

Comment: @Esailija I would never do such nonsense in the first place. Why would I have such a string to begin with? It's not a valid unicode escape sequence since that dangling quote has no place being there.

Comment: @GoogleGuy It was an example that you cannot just blindly do `json_decode( "'" $str . "'" )`, you need to escape the `$str`. This is exactly like doing mysql query with just quoting parameters but not escaping them.

Comment: @Esailija I would never do the nonsense that you're talking about in the first place. json_decode is for decoding valid JSON according to the specification. If you aren't decoding valid JSON don't use json_decode. It's that simple. I have no clue what your point is here? Is that if you want to prove to me that doing silly things is silly? I'm pretty much 100% with you on that. Anyway, I think you've gone off on a tangent from the OP's question so I'm going to discontinue this conversation as it seems to be leading absolutely nowhere.

Comment: @GoogleGuy *I would never do the nonsense that you're talking about in the first place.* Right, but this is exactly what your original comment proposes, hence the whole discussion. So you now agree it's stupid, then we both agree and all is good.

Answer (score 3):

With PHP >= 5.4 and intl extension, you have `Transliterator` class:

```
$in = '\u0041\U00000062';
$out = transliterator_create('Hex-Any')->transliterate($in);
var_dump($out); # string(2) "Ab"
```

Comment: Ahh, +1 for transliterator. I forgot all about intl :)

Comment: Unfortunately I am still on PHP 5.3 and can't use this solution :(

Answer (score 0):

[PHP strings](http://php.net/language.types.string) are the equivelant of Java byte arrays. They (*by definition*) are a 256 bit characterset (*bytes 0x00-0xff*). However, PHP string syntax already provides interpolation of certain escape character sequences in double quoted strings ([see the manual page for more details](http://php.net/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)).

However, if you are recieving a JSON encoded string the json_decode function will properly decode that string into PHP (provided it complies with the JSON specification).

```
$json_string = '"Hello\nWorld"';
var_dump(json_decode($json_string));
/*
Notice that the string output is 11 characters long and a line break character is present

string(11) "Hello
World"
*/
```

Comment: Yeah `json_deocde` is one option. But I am trying to see if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. There may be some userland implementation of that function somewhere out there written in PHP, but PHP doesn't provide a native implementation (at least none that I could find in the manual or in the PHP PECL repository). The best thing to do is not use a serialized/escaped string in PHP. Send the byte array string instead or you will have to roll your own un-escaping function.